# Elasticsearch time query with dateOptionalTime field type

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search, kibana, nosql

Is there a way to query only the time from a dateOptionalTime field in Kibana? as I can successfully query a full date using the range method

Here is a snip of my mapping

```
                "timestamp": {
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                    "type": "date"
                },
```

I just want to do something like:  timestamp: [3:31:29 TO 13:00:00]